# Django Query Sets - Finding Percentage between two QuerySets

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have got two query sets -

```
>>> region_carrier_groupby_total =
<QuerySet [{'region_carrier': 'tc2 - rc2', 'DID_Count': 2}, {'region_carrier': 'tc1 - rc1', 'DID_Count': 16}]>


>>> region_carrier_groupby_available =
<QuerySet [{'region_carrier': 'tc2 - rc2', 'DID_Count': 1}, {'region_carrier': 'tc1 - rc1', 'DID_Count': 14}]>
```

The objective here is to find the available percentage grouped by region_carrier for DID counts.
For instance -

region_carrier : tc1-rc1, Percent DID_Count = (14/16)*100
region_carrier : tc2 - rc2, Percent DID_Count = (1/2)*100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I suppose you want to do it in code not in sql:

```
total_counter = {}
for item in region_carrier_groupby_total:
    total_counter[item['region_carrier']] = item['DID_Count']

total_available = {}
for item in region_carrier_groupby_available:
    total_available[item['region_carrier']] = item['DID_Count']

result = {}
for key, total in total_counter.items():
    result[key] = total_available.get(key, 0) / total
```

Comment: I ran the code and got the error -'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'DID_Count''


`
>>> 
>>> total_available = {}
>>> for item in region_carrier_groupby_available:
...     total_available[item.region_carrier] = item.DID_Count
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'DID_Count'

`

Comment: modified response, I thought you have objects))

Comment: thanks @Anton Pomieshchenko. But instead of printing how can we save the output to a dictionary which can be passed as a context to a view ?

Comment: modified, just create a result dict and pass it to view